# View from mth row to nth row in UNIX

Tags: unix, view, row

I have a big file in z format (> 1GB). I want to view the contents of the file from 500th row to 1000th row through UNIX command. 
Can anyone tell me is there any command and syntax for this action ?

Comment: Thanks falsetru and Kjell Andreassen for your quick response. Both commands work like charm.Now, I am able to view the row values in any range of row. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `head`, `tail`

```
zcat bigfile.z | tail -n +500 | head -501
```

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat bigfile.z | sed -ne '500,1000 p'
```